# Should I use SignalR to populate a ConcurrentQueue and process it using Task Parallel Library (TPL)?

Tags: concurrency, signalr, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow, concurrentdictionary

I have a P2P client I'm building and want the inbound message flow to  use `SignalR -> System.Collections.Concurrent -> TPL Dataflow` for all inbound messages.

I would then send messages using a similar construction, either notifying existing SignalR clients, or by using SignalR to connect to another peer host, also running SignalR.

My question is what kind of intermediate object should I use between SignalR and TPL? What will ensure proper blocking and processing of messages that arrive?

- What will ensure proper sending of messages?
- What are my options and how should I choose between them?

Comment: Do you need strong ordering? Why are you thinking about using TPL Dataflow and will each message be send to the same destination? Please provide some more context.

Comment: None.  TPL Dataflow's blocks already have thread-safe input buffers. In fact, people are often using BufferBlock as an awaitable ConcurrentQueue. Why do you want to add *another* buffer in front of them?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos TPL will be handling same-device processing.  I need to connect a mesh of these TPL nodes together... and the best way to handle incoming and outgoing broadcast messages between physical nodes is SignalR / Service Bus.  So I'm connecting an internal mesh to an external mesh.

Comment: @TLDR why would that matter? You receive an event with SignalR, you post it to the root block. If you want to send, add a block that sends to the clients. If you want to throttle, set the bounded capacity of the blocks you want to throttle or batch messages with a BatchBlock.

Comment: @TLDR if you want *time* based batching/throttoling, you should probably use Reactive Extensions. Dataflow blocks buffer/batch only based on message counts. You can create your own blocks that use eg a Timespan to batch and buffer messages, but it's better to use a library that's built for that specific purpose. For example, if you only want to send 1 status update/sec to clients you can use `Throttle` to only send the last message within each second. You can convert a block to an Observable by calling `ISourceBlock.AsObservable()`. `ITargetBlock.AsObserver()` is also available

Comment: @TLDR you'll have to explain what you actually want to do and post your code if you want specific help